# Where can I find books or articles about iptables and apparmor?

Tags: iptables, apparmor

Where can I find a book or articles that doesnt tell me how to do a ls. Im looking for one where i can learn about:

-iptables
-apparmor

I know there is ufw and gufw and no gui for app armor. I want to learn iptables because I have a debian server and I dont think I can install ufw on it.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Your local library is a good start. Amazon has a load of stuff about Linux

Answer (score 0):

Per command/application/resource manuals are provided during installing, after which you can easily run `man iptables` and/or `man apparmor` in a terminal in order to view the syntax/usage of your desired application.

Good luck!